# How can I add values of form textbox using string ,for loop

Tags: javascript, html

hi guys i am new to js and html.I need a o/p as when click the button tat should show the all contents entered in form... 
My code for giving `alert` of all entered data in single
how can I add values of form textbox using string ,`for` loop  all should be only in javascript...or else give your own code with the conditions i said....

```
<html>
<head>
<title>elements in a form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function processFormData() 
{
var len= document.getElementsByTagName('name');

var str1=null;
for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
{
var str=(subscribe.name[i].value);

str=str1+str; 
 }
  alert(str);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name ="subscribe" > 
    <p><label for="name">Your Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="txt_name" value="name"></p>
    <p><label for="email">Your Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="txt_email" value="mail"></p>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="processFormData()">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you correct your code. len can not be used as a number.

Comment: Do you want to add value of multiple text boxes with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that for a start

```
var len= document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; 
// add that you want the number of element
// Change 'name' for 'input' when using 'name' you are looking for <name in the HTML
// if you want the element with the name ABC use getElementsByName()

var str1='';
for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
{
    var str=(subscribe[i].value);

    str1=str1+str; 
 }
  alert(str1);
```

jsFiddle example (in jQuery for the calling of the function) : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/HPuhg/1/

Comment: The original code, did not make more sense. I make is code work, then I tried to show him how to do the things I think he wants to do.

Comment: here you store the data in str variable and adding the str1 and str and each time str is being updated and it store in str not in str1,

Here you should use str1 = str1+str;
and alert(str1);

Comment: This will add the `value` of the submit `button` to the `String` too, i.e. it will end up as `"namemailsubmit"`, rather than `"namemail"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>elements in a form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str1=null;
function processFormData() 
{
var len= document.getElementsByTagName('name').length;

for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
{
var str=(subscribe.name[i].value);

str1=str1+str; 
 }
  alert(str1);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name ="subscribe" > 
    <p><label for="name">Your Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="txt_name" value="name"></p>
    <p><label for="email">Your Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="txt_email" value="mail"></p>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="processFormData()">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

you have just minor mistake that is you used `str` in place of `str1`; Now use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function processFormData() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i,
        len,
        stringBuffer = [],
        str;

    for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === "text") {
            stringBuffer.push(inputs[i].value);
        }
    }

    str = stringBuffer.join(""); // str contains concatenated values of all inputs
}
```

Comment: hi,thanks for ur valuable answer...i am getting o/p as i req...but one doubt is stringBuffer = [],stringbuffer.push() are js or html functions?

Comment: You're welcome :-) `stringBuffer` is just an `Array` declared using literal notation. `push` is a JavaScript method available on _all_ `Array`s. Here's some more info on the [JavaScript Array Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp). Creating an `Array`, pushing content into it and then joining at the end is an efficient way of doing `String` concatenation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function processFormData() 
{
var len= document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;


var str = '';
for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
{
 str += document.subscribe[i].value;

}
  alert(str);

}
```

Comment: hi,thanks for ur answer.....i am getting o/p partily.like"undefined namemail" can u help me to avoid tat comment undefined and place name,mail in different line

Comment: define str as array and place each value as array element that will be batter.